# sass can't compile variables: Undefined variable: "$base-line-height

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm using rails 5.1.4, bourbon 3.2.3 and neat 1.8.0 gems, sass-rails: 5.0.7, bootstrap-sass: 3.3.7 in gemfile. I have one page specific file and one custom.css file. I have my page specific file setup like this:

```
    @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
    @import "bootstrap";

    @import "normalize";
    @import "bourbon";
    @import "neat";
    @import "base/grid-settings";
    @import "base/variables";
    @import "base/forms";
    @import "base/global";
    @import "layout/header";
    @import "layout/footer";
```

I have defined all my variables in the **_variables.scss** file. However, I am getting error:

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (Undefined variable: "$base-line-
    height".). undefined variable, @include box-sizing, undefined $primary-color.
```

I can't use any of the variables I have defined in my variable.css.scss file.  It seems like sass, bourbon and neat are not correctly importing into the files.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have seen similar questions and answers like the one I have but none worked for me.  I need help here - thank you

Comment: Is `_variables.scss` supposed to have an underscore? Just wondering...

Comment: Yes, it has an underscore like so: _variables.scss in the assets/stylesheets folder.

Comment: try to import variables first and the rest css after. it's looks like the variables from variables.scss are called before this file it's loaded

Comment: Hi! So I  imported the variables file before all the other files and I'm getting a new error: Undefined variable: "$helvetica"  I'm not sure I'm understanding why this error occur again.  I defined the typography: // Typography
$sans-serif: $helvetica;
$serif: $georgia;
$base-font-family: $sans-serif;
$header-font-family: $base-font-family;  thanks :)